# SAP - Send values To RFC

Tags: saprfc

I have the following RFC structure:

```
<xds:complexType name="RFC_FUNCTION_NAME">
  <xds:sequence>
    <xds:element name="FIELD1" minOccurs="0">
      <xds:simpleType>
        <xds:restriction base="xds:string">
          <xds:maxLength value="5"/>
        </xds:restriction>
      </xds:simpleType>
    </xds:element>
  <xds:sequence>
    <xds:element name="FIELD2" minOccurs="0">
      <xds:simpleType>
        <xds:restriction base="xds:string">
          <xds:maxLength value="5"/>
        </xds:restriction>
      </xds:simpleType>
    </xds:element>
  </xds:sequence>
</xds:complexType>
```

I would like to know how to send data to SAP with this specific RFC.
How am i supposed to call this rfc to send, as an example "Hello" and "world"?

Thanks a lot

---

I need to send data to a SAP system from a non-SAP system that exposes the ability to "Call RFC".

The specifications of the RFC to call is like the one that I've posted here.
All I am supposed to archive is to update fields in a specific record.

So I imagine `FIELD1` will identify my record, and `FIELD2` will contain the value to update.

If my question still makes no sense, can you address me towards some relevant topics?

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me, could you explain more about the context? Where did you get this XSD file from? (`xds`?) What do you want to achieve? (sending `"Hello" and "world"` has no actual meaning) Remote Function Call is only a SAP protocol to communicate with an ABAP-based system (it makes no sense to use it between two non-SAP systems), from another ABAP-based system or a program in a few languages (C, PHP, Python, Java, .NET, etc.)

Comment: It seems that you are asking for some pointers. There are lots of resources in the Web, especially in https://answers.sap.com. StackOverflow is only for very precise questions, see [help](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).